# logic of restore a binary tree based on travseral results, java

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Can you help to explain the logic of how to do draw the original binary tree based on traversal results? I know pre-order and in-order traversal, but I can't figure out where to start with this question. Many thanks in advance!

```
A binary tree has this pre-order traversal result: A,B,D,H,I,E,F,C,G,K,J (TreeNodes) 
And the same tree gives the following in-order traversal: B,H,I,D,A,C,F,E,K,G,J. 
Can you draw the tree structure?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to combine both informations.
For a start:

Pre-order starts with root => A.
From in-order you can see which nodes belong to the left and right subtree from A:

left - B,H,I,D

right - C,F,E,K,G,J

From pre-order you can see: left child of A is B.
From in-order you can see which nodes belong to left and right subtree of B:

left - none

right - H,I,D

continue...